# How to make simple dynamic drop list in Laravel?

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5, foreign-keys

I'm new at Laravel and not good with syntax. I have seen many tutorials and have read many answers, but still, my mind didn't get the point of how can I have a dropdown field for a foreign key.

I'm having one table "Section" and other "Class." I want to show the name of classes in section page.

**Sections Migration**

```php
Schema::create('sections', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->integer('class_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('class_id')->references('id')->on('classses');
});
```

**Classses Migration**

```php
Schema::create('classses', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Honestly, I don't know if I should have changed my controller or not.

**Blade/View**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="title">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="cid">Class</label>
    ???????????????
</div>
```

Index Function

```
public function index()
    {        $sections = Section::all();
            return view('sections.index', compact('sections'));

        $classs = Classs::all()->pluck(['id', 'title']);
        return view('sections.index')->with('classs', $classs); }
```

Error is Unreachable Statement at line $class & Expected string, got array at ([id,'title])

Comment: So you want a dropdown with all the classes? If so, please add the migration for your classes table :)

Comment: I have updated my question. Please check it again :)

Comment: I edited my answer, see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now used this code in blade page

```
              @php
                use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
                $cid=DB::table('classses')->get();
                $uid=DB::table('users')->where('role_id','3')->get();
                $counter=0;
                @endphp

                <select class="" name="class_id">
                    <option value="null">Class</option>
                    @foreach($cid as $class)
                        @if($counter==0)
                        <option selected="selected" value="{{$class->id}}">{{$class->title}}</option>
                        {{$counter++}}
                    @else

                        <option value="{{$class->id}}">{{$class->title}}</option>
                    @endif
                            @endforeach
                </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your controller, you have a function to return the view.

Change it to include `->with()`, so you can access the classes in the view:

```
// if the controller is not for the classes, add this up top:
use App\Classs; // include model name



$classs = Classs:all();

return view('yourView')->with('classe', $classs);
```

Then, in your view, you can just do this:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="cid">Class</label>

  <select class="" name="cid">
    <option value="null">Class</option>
    @foreach($classs as $class)
      <option value="{{$class->id}}">{{$class->title}}</option>
    @endforeach
  </select>

</div>
```

It loops over all the classes in your database and creates a `<option>` element for them. Looking at your first migration, you're using the id in the other table, so you need to set that as the value.

---

Change your index function to this:

```
public function index()
{
    $sections = Section::all();
    $classs = Class::all();

    return view('sections.index')->with('sections', $sections)->with('classs', $classs);
}
```

---

> Can you tell me where can I write conditions such as select * from class where role_id=2 etc.

Basically, in an MVC framework, you do all your queries in your controller and pass the data to the view, in which you display the data.

Laravel has a [DB class](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries) which you can use for basic queries:

```
select * from class where role_id = 2
```

Would become this in Laravel, using the DB class.

```
DB::table('class')->where('role_id', 2)->get();

// or if it's a model:
Model::where('role_id', 2)->get();
```

Comment: I'm writing the upper code in Index fuction, but its giving error because of already one section code in it. Where should I write this code?

Comment: Add your index function and the error message to the post.

Comment: ' public function index()'
    {

        $sections = Section::all();
            return view('sections.index', compact('sections'));

        $classs = Classs::all()->pluck(['id', 'title']);
        return view('sections.index')->with('classs', $classs);


    }'

Comment: Could you add it to the post, makes it a little easier to read.

Comment: It works, but can you tell me where can I write conditions such as select * from class where role_id=2 etc.

Comment: Updated the answer again.

Comment: Thanks man :) Also please help me in case that when I show data like [data-myclassid="{{$cat->class_id}}"] I get id but I want name of that id as it is foreign key

Comment: You will need to look into [Eloquent Relationships in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships)